# Organization vs Architecture

Tags: architecture

Can someone explain the difference between Computer Organization vs Computer Architecture?

From what I have read architecture would be like instruction sets, addressing modes, and registers

whereas organization could things such as memory, I/O Port, or the MPC is this correct?

Answer (score 13):

Use these points to compare.

*note :use point 1 for architecture and compare it with point 1 for organization

**Architecture**

1. interface between hardware and software
2. abstract model and is programmer's view in terms of instructions,addressing modes and registers
3. describes what computer does
4. while designing computer system architecture is considered first
5. it deals with high level design issues

eg : is there a multiplication instruction??

**Organisation**

1. deals with components of connection in a system
2. expresses the realization of architecture
3. describes how computer does a task
4. organization is done on the basis of architecture
5. deals with low level design issues

eg : is there a multiplication unit or is it done by repeated addition??

Comment: Hi @nizoodxs, your question is unclear. Try the following: Explain to us what is your problem, in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: Hi @mbomb007, indeed. wrong part. Valuable lesson : Never have a 6h train trip and try to understand a technical question right after

Answer (score 4):

[This should answer your question](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_computer_organization_and_computer_architecture)

> Computer organization is how operational attributes are linked together and contribute to realise the architectural specifications.
>
> Computer architecture is the architectural attrributes like physical address memory,CPU and how they should be made and made to coordinate with each other keeping the future demands and goals in mind.
>
> Computer architecture comes before computer organiation.Its like building the design and architecture of house takes maximum time and then organisation is building house by bricks or by latest technology keeping the basic layout and architecture of house in mind.

Answer (score 3):

In describing computers, a distinction is often made between computer
architecture and computer organization.

**Computer architecture** refers to those attributes of a system visible to a
programmer or those attributes that have a direct impact on the logical
execution of a program.

Examples of architectural attributes include:

- the instruction set,
- the number of bits used to represent various data types (e.g., numbers, characters),
- I/O mechanisms, and
- techniques for addressing memory.

it is an architectural design issue whether a
computer will have a multiply instruction or not.

**Computer organization** refers to the operational units and their
interconnections that realize the architectural specifications.
Organizational attributes include:

- The hardware details transparent to the programmer, such as control
  signals;
- interfaces between the computer and peripherals; and
- the memory technology used

However, it is an organizational issue whether that instruction will be
implemented by a special multiply unit or by a mechanism that makes
repeated use of the add unit of the system.
In other words, a computer organization is designed to implement a
particular architectural specification.
The organizational decision may be based on:

- the anticipated frequency of use of the multiply instruction,
- the relative speed of the two approaches, and
- the cost and physical size of a special multiply unit

Historically, and still today, the distinction between architecture and
organization has been an important one.
Many computer manufacturers offer a family of computer models, all
with the same architecture but with differences in organization.

Consequently, the different models in the family have different price and
performance characteristics.
Furthermore, a particular architecture may span many years and
encompass a number of different computer models, while its organization
is regularly changing with changing technology.

A prominent example of an architecture which lasted over the years and included
a number of models with different speeds and costs - all with the same
architecture - is the IBM System/370 architecture.

There are different types of computers (supercomputers, mainframe
computers, microcomputers such as PCs, etc.)

Specifically in the case of microcomputers, the relationship between
architecture and organization is very close.

Changes in technology not only influence organization but also result in
the introduction of more powerful and more complex architectures.

In general, for PCs there is less of a requirement for generation-to-generation compatibility. Thus, there is more interplay between organizational and architectural
design decisions.

An example is the Reduced Instruction Set Computer (RISC).

**NOTE:** Although, the focus of this module is more on organization, a detailed
examination of architecture is also necessary, because a computer’s organization is
designed to implement a particular architectural specification. Therefore, dealing with organization requires a thorough understanding of architecture as well.

Answer (score 1):

Computer architecture is a high level view in a way that it focuses on what can be done rather than how is it done where as computer organisation focuses on the later.
An example which explains it in best way is that:-

- what maximum bit number your machine can compute this is
  **architecture**.
- where as whether it does this using 4 cycles on 16 bit machine or 1
  cycle on 64 bit machine is **organization**

Answer (score 1):

**

```
`Computer Organization                        Computer Architecture
--> often called micro architecture.         --> It is a bit high level.
-->Transparent from the coder point          --> To the coder point of view.
   of view.                                     [Ex. coder is aware of which 
                                                    instruction has been used.]
-->Corresponding to the circuit Diagram.     --> Corresponding to set of 
                                                 instructions.
-->It shows how the System works.            --> Describes what the System does.
`
```

**

Answer (score -1):

Cm Arch is the basic Characterestics of a computer and for what it created and the main majors of computer and here the speed Performance etc... Does'nt matter. 
But computer organization describes how computer should work and what Functions it should have and also the same about speed, Performance, and new Features of each computer